Working with a folder of large .txt files using Arrow, Duckdb, and Future
I am merging a folder 250 of large .txt files each approximately 1GB and over 6 million rows. I'm merging this folder with another .txt file outside of this folder that is also 1GB based on a common column.
I'm running to memory issues when attempting to merge the two even when I drop as many columns as possible.
The following are 10 rows and a few columns of three of the .txt files in the folder using dput()
profile_1<- structure(list(user_id = c(1e+06, 1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 
1000004, 1000006, 1000007, 1000008, 1000009, 1000010), fullname = c("Morgan Fabian", 
"Cally Dupe", "Horacio Bernal Gonzalez", "Deepika Babar", "Nathan Molle-Clark", 
"Imran Yasin", "Naveen Reddy", "Robert Coffman", "Master Tasco", 
"Brian Weatherford"), sex= c("F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "e", "M"), country = c("Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States", 
"Greater Perth Area", "Mexico", "Mumbai, Maharashtra, India", 
"Columbia, Missouri, United States", "United Kingdom", "Greater Hyderabad Area", 
"Huntington Beach, California, United States", "Norway", "Greater Chicago Area"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
.
.
.
profile_200<-structure(list(user_id = c(908150405, 908150406, 908150407, 908150408, 
908150409, 908150410, 908150415, 908150416, 908150417, 908150418
), fullname = c("aatm prakash chaturvedi", "ab musa", "Aabida Sayed", 
"aanand paranjape.1", "abd aziz muslim", "abdalrhman mohammad", 
"Abdul Mannan Mannan", "Aashish Punmiya", "Abdelkader Elmouetamid55", 
"abd kamal sayuti mat ali"), sex = c("e", "e", "e", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "e", "M"), country = c("India", "Ethiopia", 
"India", "India", NA, NA, "Bangladesh", "India", "France", NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
.
.
.
profile_250<- structure(list(user_id = c(2039727045, 2039727046, 2039727047, 
2039727049, 2039727050, 2039727051, 2039727052, 2039727053, 2039727054, 
2039727055), fullname = c("HOD(MECH) Trident Academy of Technololgy", 
"Hansi Figlmueller", "Mark Tan", "bianka soares", "Yuan Hu", 
"Luis Miguel Navia sanchez", "Andreia Cezar", "Luciana Roth", 
"Michał Zagajewski", "Cindy Wojdyla Cain"), sex = c("F", 
"e", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "e", "F"), country = c("India", 
"Austria", "Canada", "Brazil", "United States", "United States", 
"Brazil", "Argentina", "Poland", "United States")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

A few rows of the other_dataset that I'm merging the folder with using dput():
other_dataset<- structure(list(id = c(143, 143, 143, 379, 379, 379, 379, 379, 
419, 419), user_id = c(1309564, 2601833, 4168473, 1417698, 2991030, 
4654601, 4685011, 4748461, 1050940, 1056187), other_id = c(18564, 
18564, 18564, 26847, 26847, 26847, 26847, 26847, 30138, 30138
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

This post provides information on how to work with a large CSV file using Arrow and duckdb packages. I'm wondering if there is a way to apply it to a folder. I also have heard of future package (documentation here) that helps with parallel processing of large datasets but I am not quite sure how to integrate it into my code.
I've tried the following (Using the information in the above post.)
path_to_folder <- "/Users/myname/folder/"

my_files <- arrow::open_dataset(source = path_to_folder, pattern = "*.txt") %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb()

However, there is the following error message:
Error in ParquetFragmentScanOptions$create(...) : 
  unused argument (pattern = "*.txt")

My eventual is goal is to use the list of files in the following method for an inner_join thanks to the code provided in this post.
# function to read file and just keep certain columns
read_and_pare <- \(x) {
  x |> 
    read_delim(col_select = c(user_id, fullname)) |>
    filter(!is.na(user_id)) |>
    distinct()
}


# read data files into list, stack into one table, join to other table
purrr::map(my_files, read_and_pare) |>
  setNames(my_files) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "user_file") |>
  inner_join(other_dataset,
             join_by(user_id == user_id))

Is there a way to make use duckdb and arrow and future in my code to achieve my goal?
Update1
After the suggestion by @I_O I edited code to the following and no longer had an error message for this part:
path_to_folder <- "/Users/myname/folder/"

my_files <- arrow::open_dataset(source = path_to_folder, format= "text", delimiter= "\t") %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb()

However, when I proceeded with my merge (code provided above) the following error message appeared
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: src.
Caused by error in `enc2utf8()`:
! argument is not a character vector
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Update 2
The following is head -n 10 of the datasets in the terminal session :
First one of the files in the folder:
user_id fullname    f_prob  m_prob  white_prob  black_prob  api_prohispanic_prob    native_prob multiple_prob   highest_degree  sex_predicted   ethnicity_predicted linkedin_url    user_location   country updated_dt  numconnections
1000000.0   Morgan Fabian   0.835   0.165   0.963   0.008   0.002   0.026   0.001   0.0 Associate   F   White   linkedin.com/in/morgan-fabian-7466664a  Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States   United States   2023-07-17  12.0
1000001.0   Cally Dupe  1.0 0.0 0.584   0.002   0.08    0.001   0.002   0.331   Bachelor    F   White   linkedin.com/in/cally-dupe-b24b1337 Greater Perth Area  Australia   2023-07-03  500.0
1000002.0   Horacio Bernal Gonzalez 0.0 1.0 0.04    0.009   0.008   0.937   0.003   0.003       M   Hispanic    linkedin.com/in/horacio-bernal-gonzalez-849481145   Mexico  Mexico  2023-06-08  4.0
1000003.0   Deepika Babar   1.0 0.0 0.053   0.016   0.868   0.014   0.013   0.036       F   API linkedin.com/in/deepika-babar-3a653065  Mumbai, Maharashtra, India  India   2023-06-20  7.0
1000004.0   Nathan Molle-Clark  0.003   0.997   0.957   0.021   0.001   0.0 0.002   0.019   Bachelor    M   White   linkedin.com/in/nathanmolle-clark   Columbia, Missouri, United States   United States   2023-07-30  168.0
1000006.0   Imran Yasin 0.0 1.0 0.195   0.128   0.677   0.0 0.0 0.0     M   API linkedin.com/in/imran-yasin-b056366b    United Kingdom  United Kingdom  2023-06-24  65.0
1000007.0   Naveen Reddy    0.225   0.775   0.039   0.0 0.959   0.002   0.0 0.0     M   API linkedin.com/in/shivamogga  Greater Hyderabad Area  India   2023-06-21  238.0
1000008.0   Robert Coffman  0.004   0.996   0.984   0.0 0.0 0.002   0.001   0.013       M   White   linkedin.com/in/robert-coffman-854a191aHuntington Beach, California, United States  United States   2023-07-17  4.0
1000009.0   Master Tasco    0.5 0.5 0.279   0.625   0.009   0.013   0.008   0.066       e   Black   linkedin.com/in/master-tasco-bbb85897   Norway  Norway  2023-07-20  1.0

Second, the other_dataset
"id"    "user_id"   "gvkey"
143 1309564 18564
143 2601833 18564
143 4168473 18564
379 1417698 26847
379 2991030 26847
379 4654601 26847
379 4685011 26847
379 4748461 26847
419 1050940 30138


Could you please include an actual sample from one of the files to your question? About 10 lines, including the header. No need to load ~1GB file into text editor, head -n 10 large-text-file.txt in some unix-like environment (or e.g. git bash in Win) or gc large-text-file.txt -head 10 in Windows powershell would do. If you need to, you can change/anonymize names and other sensitive details and/or remove some irrelevant columns, but it should still have a valid structure so it would be usable to test loading into arrow / duckdb.

I'm happy to provide that. But the above dput() samples are not sufficient?

As the error message says, open_dataset does not understand the pattern argument (as e.g. list.files does). You can instead leave it at the directory path (if it contains all and only the desired files) or supply a vector of filenames obtained with list.files (see ?open_dataset).

Thank you, I was able to create my_files I updated the question with the new error message.

dput() in this context leaves too much room for assumptions. E.g from included code (which you added later) we can just assume that there are tab-separated values. Though maybe not, as there's no proof that delimiter= "\t" was actually working for you.  And what is used for NA values? In short, there's almost no guarantee we'd end up with correct test files when using your dput() results.

I just updated with head() -n 10 of the data.

Sample data
Let us first create some sample data
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)) # set the current script's location as working directory
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(duckdb)
library(arrow)


# Function to generate random IDs
generate_ids <- function(n) {
  sample(100000:999999, n, replace = TRUE)
}

# Function to generate random countries
generate_countries <- function(n) {
  countries <- c("United States", "India", "China", "Brazil", "Russia", 
                 "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Japan", "Canada")
  sample(countries, n, replace = TRUE)
}

# Create the other_dataset first (500,000 rows)
set.seed(123)
other_dataset <- data.frame(
  id = generate_ids(500000),
  user_id = generate_ids(500000),
  other_id = generate_ids(500000),
  fullname = generate_countries(500000)
)

# Optionally write other_dataset
#write.csv(other_dataset, "other_dataset.txt",row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)


# Create 3 user files with 1 million rows each for testing
for(i in 1:3) {
  # Generate base data
  n_rows <- 1000000
  
  # Ensure some overlap with other_dataset
  overlap_ids <- sample(other_dataset$user_id, n_rows * 0.3)  # 30% overlap
  random_ids <- generate_ids(n_rows * 0.7)
  
  user_data <- data.frame(
    ID2 = generate_ids(n_rows),
    fullname = generate_countries(n_rows),
    user_id = c(overlap_ids, random_ids)[1:n_rows],  # Combine and take required number
    extra_col = rnorm(n_rows)
  )
  
  # Randomize the order
  user_data <- user_data[sample(1:n_rows), ]
  
  # Write to file
  filename <- paste0("texts/user_", i, ".txt")
  write.table(user_data, filename, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
  
  # Print progress
  cat("Created:", filename, "\n")
  
  # Clean up
  rm(user_data)
  gc()
}

How to use arrow and duckdb
# load same libs as before

# Create connection
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())

# Register the folder of text files
text_files <- arrow::open_dataset(
  source = "texts/", # this is the path to your folder with the text documents!
  format = "text",
  delimiter = "\t"
) %>% 
  to_duckdb(con, "profiles")


# Register other dataset 
# assuming that "other_dataset" is loaded into the workspace
duckdb::duckdb_register(con, "other_data", other_dataset)

# Perform the merge in DuckDB
result <- dbGetQuery(con, "
  SELECT p.user_id, p.fullname, o.id, o.other_id
  FROM profiles p
  INNER JOIN other_data o ON p.user_id = o.user_id
  WHERE p.user_id IS NOT NULL
")

# Clean up
dbDisconnect(con, shutdown = TRUE)


Thank you. Two clarifying questions: 1. when I created the text_files the environment shows that this is a list of two. I'm confused about this. Because the files around 250. 2. the o. and p. specify which dataset the columns come from?

Would this approach also work for this question

Starting point would be a folder with files generated from provided data, some user_id values were changed to introduce some matches between profile-files and other_dataset, also few new NA values were introduced. From one of your attempts it was assumed that files are tab-delimited and NA values were  coded as blanks. For the process check Example data at the end of this post.
library(dbplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(duckdb)
library(glue)

# created files and content of the 1st one:
fs::dir_tree(path_to_folder) |> 
  names() |> 
  first() |> 
  read_file() |> 
  stringr::str_view()
#> D:/rtmp/RtmpoplyL6/datasetsaec68d51f6
#> ├── profile_1.txt
#> ├── profile_200.txt
#> └── profile_250.txt
#> [1] │ user_id{\t}fullname{\t}sex{\t}country
#>     │ 1050940{\t}Morgan Fabian{\t}F{\t}Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States
#>     │ 2991030{\t}Cally Dupe{\t}F{\t}Greater Perth Area
#>     │ 1000002{\t}Horacio Bernal Gonzalez{\t}M{\t}Mexico
#>     │ 1309564{\t}Deepika Babar{\t}F{\t}Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
#>     │ {\t}Nathan Molle-Clark{\t}M{\t}Columbia, Missouri, United States
#>     │ 1000006{\t}Imran Yasin{\t}M{\t}United Kingdom
#>     │ 1000007{\t}Naveen Reddy{\t}M{\t}Greater Hyderabad Area
#>     │ 1000008{\t}Robert Coffman{\t}M{\t}Huntington Beach, California, United States
#>     │ {\t}Master Tasco{\t}e{\t}Norway
#>     │ 1056187{\t}Brian Weatherford{\t}M{\t}Greater Chicago Area
#>     │


Try to keep as much as possible in duckdb. If you'd rather not write SQL, you might get away with dbplyr that translates dplyr verbs and some other function calls to SQL for you. Though in some cases it might throw in some sub-optimal aproaches, for example the way it translates dplyr::distinct() might not be ideal here, but it really depends on the actual duplicate distribution / ratio in your files. In other words, be prepared to tweak and optimize but there's no need overthink or work around problems that would not materialize from your actual dataset.
For exporting it would probably make sense to avoid yet another text file and store resulting frame in a (partitioned) parquet or duckdb on-disk database.
# DBI connection to in-memory duckdb instance
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())

# copy other_dataset from R to duckdb, 
# assume we can switch ids from numeric to integer
ref_at_ddb <- 
  other_dataset |> 
  mutate(across(ends_with("id"), as.integer)) |> 
  copy_to(dest = con, name = "ref", indexes = list("user_id"))

# create a lazy tbl to call duckdb's read_csv()
# https://duckdb.org/docs/data/csv/overview
profiles_tbl <- 
  tbl_function(con, glue(
  "read_csv('{{glob}}', 
  columns = {
    'user_id'  : 'INTEGER', 
    'fullname' : 'VARCHAR', 
    'sex'      : 'VARCHAR',
    'country'  : 'VARCHAR'
  },
  delim = '\t',
  filename = TRUE)", glob = path_to_folder / "profile*.txt", .open = "{{", .close = "}}")) |> 
  relocate(filename, .before = 1)

# create a lazy tbl for join / process / filter,
# dbplyr assumes that unknown functions in mutate are known for remote server,
# so we can just use duckdb functions, e.g.
# parse_filename() to extract file portion of full paths -- 
# https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/char#parse_filenamepath-trim_extension-separator
result_tbl <- 
  inner_join(ref_at_ddb, profiles_tbl, by = "user_id") |> 
  mutate(filename = parse_filename(filename)) |> 
  distinct(user_id, filename, .keep_all = TRUE)

# it's still just a query,
# though we can check few first rows without going through all input files:
# (note how number of total rows is unknown)
result_tbl |> 
  print(n = 5)
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 7]
#> # Database: DuckDB v1.1.0 [margus@Windows 10 x64:R 4.4.2/:memory:]
#>      id user_id other_id filename        fullname                  sex   country                   
#>   <int>   <int>    <int> <chr>           <chr>                     <chr> <chr>                     
#> 1   419 1050940    30138 profile_200.txt Aashish Punmiya           M     India                     
#> 2   143 1309564    18564 profile_1.txt   Deepika Babar             F     Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
#> 3   419 1056187    30138 profile_250.txt Mark Tan                  M     Canada                    
#> 4   379 1417698    26847 profile_200.txt Abdelkader Elmouetamid55  e     France                    
#> 5   143 4168473    18564 profile_250.txt Luis Miguel Navia sanchez M     United States             
#> # ℹ more rows

# if you do need to get results at this point, call collect():
result_tbl |> 
  collect()  
#> # A tibble: 10 × 7
#>       id user_id other_id filename        fullname                  sex   country                   
#>    <int>   <int>    <int> <chr>           <chr>                     <chr> <chr>                     
#>  1   419 1050940    30138 profile_200.txt Aashish Punmiya           M     India                     
#>  2   419 1056187    30138 profile_250.txt Mark Tan                  M     Canada                    
#>  3   143 1309564    18564 profile_250.txt Michał Zagajewski         e     Poland                    
#>  4   379 2991030    26847 profile_1.txt   Cally Dupe                F     Greater Perth Area        
#>  5   379 1417698    26847 profile_200.txt Abdelkader Elmouetamid55  e     France                    
#>  6   143 4168473    18564 profile_250.txt Luis Miguel Navia sanchez M     United States             
#>  7   419 1056187    30138 profile_1.txt   Brian Weatherford         M     Greater Chicago Area      
#>  8   143 1309564    18564 profile_1.txt   Deepika Babar             F     Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
#>  9   419 1050940    30138 profile_1.txt   Morgan Fabian             F     Kannapolis, North Carolin…
#> 10   143 4168473    18564 profile_200.txt Abdul Mannan Mannan       M     Bangladesh

# to let duckdb handle writing files, fetch result_tbl's SQL and use it in duckdb `COPY ...` query:
show_query(result_tbl)
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT id, user_id, other_id, filename, fullname, sex, country
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT
#>     q01.*,
#>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, filename ORDER BY id) AS col01
#>   FROM (
#>     SELECT
#>       id,
#>       user_id,
#>       other_id,
#>       parse_filename(filename) AS filename,
#>       fullname,
#>       sex,
#>       country
#>     FROM (
#>       SELECT "ref".*, filename, fullname, sex, country
#>       FROM "ref"
#>       INNER JOIN (
#> FROM read_csv('D:/rtmp/RtmpoplyL6/datasetsaec68d51f6/profile*.txt', 
#> columns = {
#>   'user_id'  : 'INTEGER', 
#>   'fullname' : 'VARCHAR', 
#>   'sex'      : 'VARCHAR',
#>   'country'  : 'VARCHAR'
#> },
#> delim = '    ',
#> filename = TRUE)
#>       ) RHS
#>         ON ("ref".user_id = RHS.user_id)
#>     ) q01
#>   ) q01
#> ) q01
#> WHERE (col01 = 1)
dbExecute(con, 
  glue("COPY ({subquery}) TO '{output}' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIM '\t');", 
       subquery = sql_render(result_tbl), 
       output = path_to_folder / "out.txt"
  )
)
#> [1] 10
dbDisconnect(con)

# out.txt in output folder:
fs::dir_tree(path_to_folder)
#> D:/rtmp/RtmpoplyL6/datasetsaec68d51f6
#> ├── out.txt
#> ├── profile_1.txt
#> ├── profile_200.txt
#> └── profile_250.txt

# and its content:
read_file(path_to_folder / "out.txt") |> 
  stringr::str_view()
#> [1] │ id{\t}user_id{\t}other_id{\t}filename{\t}fullname{\t}sex{\t}country
#>     │ 419{\t}1050940{\t}30138{\t}profile_1.txt{\t}Morgan Fabian{\t}F{\t}Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States
#>     │ 143{\t}4168473{\t}18564{\t}profile_200.txt{\t}Abdul Mannan Mannan{\t}M{\t}Bangladesh
#>     │ 143{\t}1309564{\t}18564{\t}profile_250.txt{\t}Michał Zagajewski{\t}e{\t}Poland
#>     │ 419{\t}1050940{\t}30138{\t}profile_200.txt{\t}Aashish Punmiya{\t}M{\t}India
#>     │ 143{\t}1309564{\t}18564{\t}profile_1.txt{\t}Deepika Babar{\t}F{\t}Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
#>     │ 419{\t}1056187{\t}30138{\t}profile_1.txt{\t}Brian Weatherford{\t}M{\t}Greater Chicago Area
#>     │ 379{\t}1417698{\t}26847{\t}profile_200.txt{\t}Abdelkader Elmouetamid55{\t}e{\t}France
#>     │ 143{\t}4168473{\t}18564{\t}profile_250.txt{\t}Luis Miguel Navia sanchez{\t}M{\t}United States
#>     │ 419{\t}1056187{\t}30138{\t}profile_250.txt{\t}Mark Tan{\t}M{\t}Canada
#>     │ 379{\t}2991030{\t}26847{\t}profile_1.txt{\t}Cally Dupe{\t}F{\t}Greater Perth Area
#>     │


Adressing dplyr::distinct() question in comments

/../ I'd love to understand more about why would the dplyr::distinct() not work? / .. /

Well, it's not dplyr::distinct() but distinct() from dbplyr, https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/ .
DuckDB itself is not an "R thing", it's a separate in-process SQL server with its own data access and processing mechanism, separated from R. It's just launched and controlled from R though duckdb DBI interface, the duckdb R package.  That's also the reason for the "Try to keep as much as possible in duckdb" remark above -- if you'd use anything that must be executed in R environment on that dataset (e.g. dplyr::distinct() ), whole dataset must be materialized and transferred from DuckDB to R first, this would cancel (most) benefits of DuckDB, it's slow and you'd probably run out of memory. dbplyr basically translates dplyr verbs (mutate, filter, distinct etc ) along with a fixed set of other more common method calls and expressions into SQL, the output of show_query(result_tbl) in example above.
Key point is that nothing get's executed in DuckDB before it's time to compute / collect data, DuckDB instance receives final SQL query, works out optimized execution plan and then starts processing -- inner_join, mutate, distinct from dbplyr in example above do not trigger any data access, they just generate SQL; while print, collect, dbExecute do trigger actual materialization, generated SQL gets sent to DuckDB and it returns something back to R.
In generated SQL, distinct() is responsible for
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, filename ORDER BY id) AS col01

and
WHERE (col01 = 1)

parts, I wouldn't say it's not going to work, it just looks computationally expensive. But I'd certainly give it a go, first with a single input file and then gradually moving towards full dataset to see how it scales, with DuckDB's full-query optimization magic, performance might still be acceptable.
There's some controversy in dbplyr as it seemingly provides a nice abstraction to generate SQL without knowing too much about the syntax, but in reality one should be careful what and how to use in a dbplyr workflow, viable approaches often depend on the actual SQL backend and generated SQL should also be checked before blindly running it on larger datasets.
As an alternative in the dplyr-like workflow domain, you might want to evaluate duckplyr. It bypasses SQL layers (no DBI on the R side, no SQL parser on the DuckDB side) and communicates directly with DuckDB execution engine, this means more flexibility when expressing dplyr verbs. I'd start with https://duckdb.org/2024/04/02/duckplyr.html for some context & background.

Example data:
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(glue)

df_lst <- list(
  profile_1 = structure(list(user_id = c(1e+06, 1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 
1000004, 1000006, 1000007, 1000008, 1000009, 1000010), fullname = c("Morgan Fabian", 
"Cally Dupe", "Horacio Bernal Gonzalez", "Deepika Babar", "Nathan Molle-Clark", 
"Imran Yasin", "Naveen Reddy", "Robert Coffman", "Master Tasco", 
"Brian Weatherford"), sex= c("F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "e", "M"), country = c("Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States", 
"Greater Perth Area", "Mexico", "Mumbai, Maharashtra, India", 
"Columbia, Missouri, United States", "United Kingdom", "Greater Hyderabad Area", 
"Huntington Beach, California, United States", "Norway", "Greater Chicago Area"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), 
  profile_200 = structure(list(user_id = c(908150405, 908150406, 908150407, 908150408, 
908150409, 908150410, 908150415, 908150416, 908150417, 908150418
), fullname = c("aatm prakash chaturvedi", "ab musa", "Aabida Sayed", 
"aanand paranjape.1", "abd aziz muslim", "abdalrhman mohammad", 
"Abdul Mannan Mannan", "Aashish Punmiya", "Abdelkader Elmouetamid55", 
"abd kamal sayuti mat ali"), sex = c("e", "e", "e", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "e", "M"), country = c("India", "Ethiopia", 
"India", "India", NA, NA, "Bangladesh", "India", "France", NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), 
  profile_250 = structure(list(user_id = c(2039727045, 2039727046, 2039727047, 
2039727049, 2039727050, 2039727051, 2039727052, 2039727053, 2039727054, 
2039727055), fullname = c("HOD(MECH) Trident Academy of Technololgy", 
"Hansi Figlmueller", "Mark Tan", "bianka soares", "Yuan Hu", 
"Luis Miguel Navia sanchez", "Andreia Cezar", "Luciana Roth", 
"Michał Zagajewski", "Cindy Wojdyla Cain"), sex = c("F", 
"e", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "e", "F"), country = c("India", 
"Austria", "Canada", "Brazil", "United States", "United States", 
"Brazil", "Argentina", "Poland", "United States")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)

other_dataset <- structure(list(id = c(143, 143, 143, 379, 379, 379, 379, 379, 
419, 419), user_id = c(1309564, 2601833, 4168473, 1417698, 2991030, 
4654601, 4685011, 4748461, 1050940, 1056187), other_id = c(18564, 
18564, 18564, 26847, 26847, 26847, 26847, 26847, 30138, 30138
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

(path_to_folder <- fs::dir_create(tempfile("datasets")))
#> D:/rtmp/RtmpoplyL6/datasetsaec68d51f6

set.seed(42)
# change example input so some user_id-s of profiles would have a match in other_dataset & 
# set few user_id values to NA;
# write as tab-separated values to path_to_folder/*.txt, use blank for NA
df_lst |> 
  map(\(profile_df) within(
    profile_df, 
    { 
      user_id[sample(1:10, 5)] <- other_dataset$user_id[sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE)]
      user_id[sample(1:10, 2)] <- NA
    })) |> 
  print() |> 
  iwalk(\(df, name) write_delim(df, delim = "\t", na = "", file = path_to_folder / paste0(name,".txt")))
#> $profile_1
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    user_id fullname                sex   country                                    
#>      <dbl> <chr>                   <chr> <chr>                                      
#>  1 1050940 Morgan Fabian           F     Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States  
#>  2 2991030 Cally Dupe              F     Greater Perth Area                         
#>  3 1000002 Horacio Bernal Gonzalez M     Mexico                                     
#>  4 1309564 Deepika Babar           F     Mumbai, Maharashtra, India                 
#>  5      NA Nathan Molle-Clark      M     Columbia, Missouri, United States          
#>  6 1000006 Imran Yasin             M     United Kingdom                             
#>  7 1000007 Naveen Reddy            M     Greater Hyderabad Area                     
#>  8 1000008 Robert Coffman          M     Huntington Beach, California, United States
#>  9      NA Master Tasco            e     Norway                                     
#> 10 1056187 Brian Weatherford       M     Greater Chicago Area                       
#> 
#> $profile_200
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>      user_id fullname                 sex   country   
#>        <dbl> <chr>                    <chr> <chr>     
#>  1 908150405 aatm prakash chaturvedi  e     India     
#>  2 908150406 ab musa                  e     Ethiopia  
#>  3 908150407 Aabida Sayed             e     India     
#>  4        NA aanand paranjape.1       M     India     
#>  5        NA abd aziz muslim          M     <NA>      
#>  6 908150410 abdalrhman mohammad      M     <NA>      
#>  7   4168473 Abdul Mannan Mannan      M     Bangladesh
#>  8   1050940 Aashish Punmiya          M     India     
#>  9   1417698 Abdelkader Elmouetamid55 e     France    
#> 10 908150418 abd kamal sayuti mat ali M     <NA>      
#> 
#> $profile_250
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>       user_id fullname                                 sex   country      
#>         <dbl> <chr>                                    <chr> <chr>        
#>  1 2039727045 HOD(MECH) Trident Academy of Technololgy F     India        
#>  2 2039727046 Hansi Figlmueller                        e     Austria      
#>  3    1056187 Mark Tan                                 M     Canada       
#>  4 2039727049 bianka soares                            F     Brazil       
#>  5 2039727050 Yuan Hu                                  M     United States
#>  6    4168473 Luis Miguel Navia sanchez                M     United States
#>  7 2039727052 Andreia Cezar                            F     Brazil       
#>  8         NA Luciana Roth                             F     Argentina    
#>  9    1309564 Michał Zagajewski                        e     Poland       
#> 10         NA Cindy Wojdyla Cain                       F     United States

Created on 2024-12-31 with reprex v2.1.1
